# Unknown Math error while creating a WSTP link

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

When I was executing this code

```
link = LinkCreate[LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
```

I was getting the response as 
"LinkOpen::linke: Unknown MathLink problem encountered.."
or sometimes the system freezes. I had to abort the execution.
Could anyone please help me out here?

Thanks,

Sudharsan

Comment: It will be hard to help without more info, if we can help at all. Do you have an available TCP/IP port to use? I’d also try emailing support to see what they say since this seems a subtle error that maybe only someone who can see the source code can debug.

Comment: Thank you b3m2a1, as per you suggestion, emailed the support. They told to disable firewall settings to execute the LinkOpen call.